# Examples of projects that have been implemented successfully using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I understand the foundation of SharePoint but there is one thing that I can't find enough answer from my question.

What good examples are there, where a SharePoint project is used in a real business? One concrete example is to create a HR project to review the candidate's profile and other one is to create a survey.

Comment: Your question is really unclear regarding the type of answer you are expecting. Are you looking for what can be done with the plateform ? If it's possible to create a HR / Survey solution ? If you clarify your question we can help you faster and better.

Comment: A project that has been implemented and succeed project solution. I hope that I have provided a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title, although I'm not sure this open question is supported by SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are countless of live & successfull solution built above / with SharePoint.
As soon as you have collaboration needs, document management requirements, workflows, search, external services integration, etc. you'll find real world case studies described in these 200+ list : http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Search_Results.aspx?Type=1&Keywords=SharePoint&LangID=46.

Regarding your query, you can customize an existing site template for your HR needs like the ones listed here : http://www.microsoft.com/government/en-us/campaigns/pages/sharepoint-templates.aspx

> **Employee Activities Site** The Employee Activities Site application
>   template helps departments, such as HR and marketing, to manage the
>   creation of and attendance at employee events.
>
> **Employee Training Scheduling and Materials** The Employee Training
>   Scheduling and Materials application template helps instructors to add
>   new courses and to organize course materials. Employees use the site
>   to schedule attendance at courses, to track courses they've attended
>   and to provide feedback.
>
> **Absence Request and Vacation Schedule Management** The Absence Request
>   and Vacation Schedule Management application template helps
>   departments to manage requests for out of office days and provides
>   dashboards showing which users are assigned to each set of
>   responsibilities.
>
> **Event Planning** The Event Planning application template helps teams to
>   organize events efficiently through the use of online registration,
>   schedules, communication and feedback.
>
> **Resource Availability Site** The Resources Availability Site application
>   template helps users view, manage, track, and approve resources.

And for the survey need, you can create survey lists based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A good example is sharing information, sharepoint does good at that... i work for a company called eshare and we develop customised sharepoint portal for our clients, mainly for boards of directors where the receptionist or in meetings you can store your minutes of meetings (small part of a complex product). This allows all users who have access to these documents to read them before the meeting to prepare themselfs and to read the outcome afterwards. This is the only good example i could use as i work for them but there are many others that you could see online.

You could do either intranet or extranet. eShare is extranet and is a hosted solution by eshare at a dedicated server for more detailed info on eshare http://www.eshare.co.uk (website is also made using sharepoint ;) )as for other examples you could easily search on google :)

hope it explains your question